# Поддерживает ли windows 10 ASLR?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-10, компоновщик

Я скомпилировал программу  `ASLRTest.exe` в `msvc 2017` (с опцией `Randomized Base Adress: Yes (/DYNAMICBASE)`):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello, kitty\n";
    int i;
    std::cin >> i;
    return 0;
}
```

Я запустил эту программу несколько раз. И просматривал статистику загрузок. Оказалось что программа в течение сеанса операционной системы грузит образ файла по одному и тому же адресу. Это ошибка?

[image: статистика]

Comment: ... `Параметр /DYNAMICBASE изменяет заголовок исполняемого образа, файла .dll или .exe, чтобы указать, следует ли случайно перебазировать приложение во время загрузки, и включает рандомизацию распределения виртуальных адресов, которая влияет на расположение виртуальной памяти в кучах, стеках. и другие выделения операционной системы.`

Comment: @ヒミコ, ну да. Именно за это он и отвечает. Или что вы хотели сказать?

Comment: Перечитайте еще раз... **которая влияет на расположение виртуальной памяти в кучах, стеках**.

Comment: @ヒミコ ну там ведь указано еще про случайное перебазирование приложения во время загрузки. Dormann тут точно также тестировал https://twitter.com/wdormann/status/930916460473577474

Comment: Теперь запустите его на другой системе - адрес должен быть другим. Или просто переименуйте файл. Он будет загружаться не по предпочитаемому адресу, а по случайно выбранному.

Comment: @user7860670, да я уже успел провести небольшой тест, после перезагрузки системы адрес действительно поменялся. Видимо система не гарантируют что в течение сессии операционной системы адрес будет постоянно меняться. Похожие мысли я нашел здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44842899/why-doesnt-windows-keep-randomizing-the-base-address-of-my-executable

Comment: Смысл ASLR прежде всего в загрузке не по предпочитаемому адресу, а не в загрузке каждый раз по новому адресу.